# Sqoop Import error while loading data from MySQL to HDFS

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to load data from MySQL to HDFS by using below query:

```
$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/userdb \
--username root --password pwd \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --table import-all-tables \
--m 1 --target-dir /user/cloudera/foldername
```

I get a "communications link failure error".

1. MYSQL Source: Installed in my local computer
2. HDFS Destination: Cloudera in virtual machine

Please help me how to load data from my local computer to cloudera HDFS .

Comment: What do the error logs say?  What does the DB log say?  What have you tried in terms of troubleshooting?

Comment: The Ip is a localhost ip. sqoop is installed on the cloudera server right? you cant access your data with your local ip. You need to have a fixed ip

Comment: can you please send tips to fix this issue